# How can we inherit a JS file from one module to another JS file in another module in odoo10

Tags: javascript, jquery, odoo-10

I want know how a JS file in module1 can be inherited from another JS file in another module2 in odoo10.

I want to inherit a JS file named 'dialog.js'in module named "module1" to a JS file named 'script.js' which is in another module named "module2"

Answer (score 1):

Odoo uses a [REQUIREJS](http://requirejs.org/) style of javascript modularisation. Here is how you can create a new js module which has inherited the characteristics or another.

```
odoo.define('addon_name.jsmodule', function (require) {
"user strict"
    var module = require('other.module');
    module.extend({
        // Your extension here
    });
});
```

Now within the scope of your jsmodule you have access to all of the attributes of the `other.module` plus or minus your modifications.

You can see examples of this in `/addons/web/static/src/js/framework/data.js` this is a (to me anyway) a complex topic. There are entire university courses on javascript inheritance. I am not an expert either. In the `framework` directory there are many examples of class extension. This is where I would go to get a better understanding of how to inherit the properties of an existing class.

You can also review the documentation [Odoo Javascript](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/javascript.html),[Odoo JS Extensions](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/howtos/web.html)

Make sure you have a cup of coffee. Enjoy!